# Open a .pkl file or convert a .pkl file to a csv file without re-writing the whole code

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pickle

```
I have tried to open this pickle file in this format.
import pickle
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV as CCV
f=open("model1.pkl", "rb")
obj=pickle.load(f)
obj.method("isotonic")
s=f.read()
print(s)
```

And this format but I just cannot open it.
import os,pickle
if os.path.isfile("model19.pkl"):
f=open("model19.pkl","rb", 4096)
s=f.read()
a=pickle.load("myfile.txt")
obj.method("isotonic")
print(s)
print(a)
f.close()
else:
print("File does not exist"

If not able to open when it is in pickle file, How can I open in a csv file? Do I need to re-write the entire code?